# Forward gas fee to gnosis safe

Tags: gnosis-safe

I'd like to forward the gas fee of this tx to my gnosis safe:

```
  function withdraw() external onlyOwner {
    payable(vault).transfer(address(this).balance);
  }
```

*Note*: `vault` is the Gnosis Safe address.

Is this possible ?

Comment: What do you mean forward? Make the gnosis safe pay for the tx fee?

Comment: Yes. But also it seems like my problem is related to eip-2929: https://help.gnosis-safe.io/en/articles/5249851-why-can-t-i-transfer-eth-from-a-contract-into-a-safe

Answer (score 1):

use `vault.call{value: address(this).balance}('')` to forward the call with the full gas. Otherwise, it can be specified via  `vault.call{value: address(this).balance, gas: 50000}('')` for example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the only way to "forward" gas costs is to delete a bunch of stored data. (gas rebate tokens)

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

IGNORE my answer. It’s not correct, I got confused, see comments.

**Original**

So you can make an address pay for the Tx gas fee by using `payable()`.

```js
payable(vault).transfer(address(this).balance);
```

Here the `vault` (Gnosis safe address) will pay for the Tx gas fee.

This requires setting up a [Spending limit](https://help.gnosis-safe.io/en/articles/4667979-set-up-and-use-spending-limits) for the smart contract sending the funds.

Be careful though !

[EIP-2929](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2929) broke contract to contract [`transfer` for Gnosis safes](https://help.gnosis-safe.io/en/articles/5249851-why-can-t-i-transfer-eth-from-a-contract-into-a-safe). And you have to use [EIP-2930](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2930) `accessList` to go around the new limitation.

More details about that [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/123750/how-to-implement-eip-2930-access-list).

Comment: Be careful, payable by itself doesn't pay transaction fees. The whole thing `payable(vault).transfer(address(this).balance)` transfers any existing balance to the vault contract. It doesn't pay any transaction fee.

Comment: Ok thanks. I got confused in the stress of the moment then. So you confirm that the Tx fee is paid by the account calling the smart contract method (in that case owner) ?

Comment: The transaction fees are always paid by the transaction's signer account.